# How to get last group in Pandas' groupBy?

Tags: python, pandas

I wish to get the last group of my group by:

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M')).groups[-1]:
```

but that gives the error:

> KeyError: -1

Using `get_group` is useless as I don't know the last group's value (unless there's a specific way to get that value?). Also I might want to get the last 2 groups, etc

How do I do this?

Comment: You want the group or the last value? for example `df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M')).last()` returns the last value for each group

Comment: @EdChum No, I want the last 1 group. I wish to iterate over that group's data (might become n groups - the 'M' might change as well to another period)

Comment: Could you try this: `df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M')).get_group(df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M')).last().iloc[-1].name)`

Comment: I think in that case I'll post an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `last` which computes the last values for each group and use `iloc` to get the row values and access the index group values using the `name` attribute, there is probably a better way but unable to figure this out yet:

```
In [170]:
# dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['1','2','2','4','5','2'], 'b':np.random.randn(6)})
df
Out[170]:
   a         b
0  1  0.097176
1  2 -1.400536
2  2  0.352093
3  4 -0.696436
4  5 -0.308680
5  2 -0.217767
In [179]:

gp = df.groupby('a', sort=False)
gp.get_group(df.groupby('a').last().iloc[-1].name)
Out[179]:
   a         b
4  5  0.608724
In [180]:

df.groupby('a').last().iloc[-2:]
Out[180]:
          b
a          
4  0.390451
5  0.608724
In [181]:

mult_groups = gp.last().iloc[-2:].index
In [182]:

for gp_val in mult_groups:
    print(gp.get_group(gp_val))
   a         b
3  4  0.390451
   a         b
4  5  0.608724
```

Comment: mmm, I'm using date_index so I'm fine, but your example has group i=4 as last group, and not i=5 as last group. You might want to add that you can pass `sort=False`. Although it might not matter with the duplicates in `a`

Comment: Sure, good point it's unclear to me if the dict that is returned from `groups` is in sorted form or not and whether it's safe to attemp to sort it, this won't work if you have multiple values in the value column (which are the group values) e.g. if you use the following: `import operator
sorted_groups = sorted(gp.groups.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))`

Answer (score 5):

Using Ed's example
You can slice out the last group. The groups iterate in the correct order (meaning the given order, or sorted, as determined by the options).

```
In [12]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['1','2','2','4','5','2'], 'b':np.random.randn(6)})

In [13]: g = df.groupby('a')

In [14]: g.groups
Out[14]: {'1': [0], '2': [1, 2, 5], '4': [3], '5': [4]}

In [15]: import itertools

In [16]: list(itertools.islice(g,len(g)-1,len(g)))
Out[16]: 
[('5',    a         b
  4  5 -0.644857)]
```

Comment: I was wondering whether or not the groups were in sorted order or not, I assumed they were but wasn't sure thanks for clarifying this

Comment: you can disable the sort (enabled by default) with `df.groupby('x', sort=False)`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is to convert the groups to a DataFrame and index it as you would a DataFrame. The resulting DataFrame has a row for each group, there the first column is the group index, and the second column is the DataFrame from that group. The one-liner for the last group's DataFrame is:

```
last_dataframe = pd.Dataframe(df.groupby('whatever')).iloc[-1, 1]
```

If you want the index and group:

```
last_group = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('whatever')).iloc[-1, :]
```

`last_group[0]` is the index of the last group, and
`last_group[1]` is the DataFrame of the last group